# Running 2 Flask Applications Inside Single Docker Container

Tags: flask, dockerfile

I'm on a team that is developing fuzzy text matching system for an insurance client and right now I've been tasked with the system frontend (UI & Frontend API). My requirements are that both Flask applications have to run within a single Docker container that gets pushed to a kubernetes pod.

The frontend UI is an Angular application that is being packaged and deployed into the Flask server that is also hosting the Frontend API application which has been written in Python. The frontend UI needs to run on port 4200 and the API application is to run on port 12000.

I'm using a single Docker file using a multi-stage build so I build the Angular application first and copy it's packages into a directory on the server that runs the API application called 'static' so all of the Angular package assets are in that folder. Once that is completed I then build the API application.

So my question would be how can I or should I configure my Docker file so that the frontend UI will run on port 4200 and the API application will run on port 12000.

Comment: So after more research into this question I've come to the conclusion that the best approach for me to use to accomplish this is to use the 'Supervisor' Process Manager so I'm headed down that path.